# Android tabhost: How to set the tabwidget over the tabcontent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

I received a design where I have a custom tabbar, and one of the tabbar's tabs is bigger than the others.

This part was easy to do, but that bigger portion of the tab was suposed be over the tabcontent object, so when the content get scrolled, that tab will be 'floating' over it.

This was what I got first:
[image]

I seted the magin_top of the tabcontent to -4dip (size of the bigger portion) and the content moved up, but it moved over the tabwidget.

This is what happened then: 
[image]

I'm new to android development, so I tried to look for anything like a z-index, I found a bringToFront() and a bringToFromChild(), but I guess they were not what I was looking for.

This is what I'm trying to do: [image]
Where the red is the content of a tab

Answer (score 0):

Set the same Red background in `parent container` of `tab-widget` layout file so you can get a View like the last image.

Comment: that would be the first case, I'm trying to make the content scroll behind the tab

Comment: i mean set the red baground to parent layout of your tab-widget layout file i had edited my answer.